# How to drop duplicates based on two or more subsets criteria in Pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Lets say this is my data-frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'bio' : ['1', '1', '1', '4'],
                'center' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three'],
                'outcome' : ['f','t','f','f'] })
```

It looks like this ...

```
  bio center outcome
0   1    one       f
1   1    one       t
2   1    two       f
3   4  three       f
```

I want to drop row 1 because it has the same bio & center as row 0.
I want to keep row 2 because it has the same bio but different center then row 0.

Something like this won't work based on drop_duplicates input structure but it's what I am trying to do

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = 'bio' & subset = 'center' )
```

Any suggestions ?

edit : changed df a bit to fit example by correct answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Here's the correct way:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['bio', 'center', 'outcome'])
```

Or in this specific case, just simply:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Both return the following:

```
  bio center outcome
0   1    one       f
2   1    two       f
3   4  three       f
```

Take a look at the `df.drop_duplicates` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for syntax details. `subset` should be a sequence of column labels.

Comment: good point. I overlooked the definition of 'subset'. Just waisted an hour on a simple issue :)

Answer (score 1):

The previous **Answer** was very helpful. It helped me. I also needed to add something in code to get what I wanted. So, I wanted to add here that.

The data-frame:

```
  bio center outcome
0   1    one       f
1   1    one       t
2   1    two       f
3   4  three       f
```

After implementing `drop_duplicates`:

```
  bio center outcome
0   1    one       f
2   1    two       f
3   4  three       f
```

Notice at the index. They got messed up. If anyone wants to back the normal indexes i.e. `0, 1, 2` from `0, 2, 3`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['bio', 'center', 'outcome'], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  bio center outcome
0   1    one       f
1   1    two       f
2   4  three       f
```