# How to remove duplicates within a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am looking to remove duplicates "within" a group. How can I do this in the most efficient way?

I have tried just grouping the data by ID, but since the companies can raise the same type of investment rounds in different years, this approach leads me to a wrong result.

I have data like this:

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| ID |   Type    | seed_year | series_a_year |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | seed      |      2014 |             0 |
|  2 | seed      |      2014 |             0 |
|  2 | seed      |      2015 |             0 |
|  3 | seed      |      2012 |             0 |
|  3 | series_a  |         0 |          2014 |
|  3 | series_a  |         0 |          2015 |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

Where my desired output would be:

```
+----+----------+-----------+---------------+
| ID |   Type   | seed_year | series_a_year |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | seed     |      2014 |             0 |
|  2 | seed     |      2014 |             0 |
|  3 | seed     |      2012 |             0 |
|  3 | series_a |         0 |          2014 |
+----+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I would like to keep the first (oldest) funding round.

Comment: Are you after `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Type'])` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop duplicates based on two or more subsets criteria in Pandas data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497835/how-to-drop-duplicates-based-on-two-or-more-subsets-criteria-in-pandas-data-fram)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 'subset' argument of `.drop_duplicates()`:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Type'], keep='first')
```

Comment: Would this require my data to be sorted in a particular way?

Comment: Yes... you'd need to sort it so that the values you want to keep come first... so by year for instance... (although your example already appears to be in year order)

Comment: yes, the order is important here, because that will determine which rows are going to be dropped. is there a particular logic as to why you kept the rows in your question, beyond the (ID - Type) groups?

Comment: @dabe16ab you might also be able to do `df.groupby(['ID', 'Type'], as_index=False).min()`

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `keep` is by default `'first'`
So you may omit that.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Type'])
```