# Drop duplicate values from hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a hierarchical index. I want to get the unique values for each index. How can I do that?

```
Party            Name                           
Bahujan         Agiaon  
                Agiaon  
                Amarpur 
Samajwadi       Vaishali    
                Vaishali    
                Wazirganj   
                Wazirganj
```

How can I drop the duplicate values in Name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to drop duplicates based on two or more subsets criteria in Pandas data-frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497835/how-to-drop-duplicates-based-on-two-or-more-subsets-criteria-in-pandas-data-fram)

Comment: Hi again. You can use ``drop_duplicates`` on the index (assuming you just need the index, not the rest of the dataset. But if you do need the entire dataframe, you need to consider what to do with the values. ttps://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: How to keep only hierarchical index and drop all the columns in final result?

Answer (score 0):

You can factorize the index , then convert to series and keep only the ones which aren't duplicated:

```
df[~pd.Series(df.index.factorize()[0]).duplicated().to_numpy()]
```

---

```
Party           Name
Bahujan       Agiaon
              Amarpur
Samajwadi     Vaishali
              Wazirganj
```

Or for just a dataframe with unique indexes:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.unique())
```

Comment: If I have other columns and these two indexes, how to get the result as only these indexes and no columns?

Comment: @Deepak add `.index` at the end of the code? or for a blank multiindexed dataframe see second solution